# Select Row with highest value between two tables while also selecting other columns in group by

Tags: mysql

Been stuck on figuring out the query for this.

Offers Database contains these columns:
Customer_ID, Date, Trigger, Priority, PriorityOverRide.

I have the query that selects the largest value between Priority and PriorityOverride but I cant seem to figure out to also select the row where the value was taken from.

Here is my query at the moment:

```
SELECT
Customer_ID,
CASE WHEN offers.PriorityOverride > 0 THEN offers.PriorityOverride ELSE 
Priority END AS 'Priority'
FROM
(
SELECT
    Customer_ID,
    MAX(Priority) AS Priority,
    MAX(PriorityOverride) AS PriorityOverride
FROM
    offers
GROUP BY
    CUstomer_ID
) AS offers
```

The above query chooses the MAX value of Priority and PriorityOverride and selects the one that bigger.

Now Im having trouble with also selecting the Date and Trigger column where the Priority was selected from.

Edit:
More information:
PriorityOverride can be null or empty but if it is not empty or null, its value supersedes whatever Priority has.

Edit2:
Here is my updated Query:

```
SELECT Customer_ID, Date, Trigger_1, Priority, PriorityOverride
  FROM Offers
  WHERE (Customer_ID, Priority) in (
    SELECT
        Customer_ID,
        CASE WHEN
            MAX(PriorityOverride) > 0
        THEN
            MAX(PriorityOverride)
        ELSE
            MAX(Priority)
        END AS 'Priority'
    FROM
        Offers
    GROUP BY
        Customer_ID
  ) 
  OR (Customer_ID, PriorityOverride) in (
    SELECT
        Customer_ID,
        CASE WHEN
            MAX(PriorityOverride) > 0
        THEN
            MAX(PriorityOverride)
        ELSE
            MAX(Priority)
        END AS 'Priority'
    FROM
        Offers
    GROUP BY
        Customer_ID
  )
```

However the above query gives me an error of " Errors: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','."

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: (Incedentally, this is the most frequently asked question under this tag. Sometimes, it's correctly answered too!)

Comment: Oh, and 'propensity' <> 'priority'

Comment: I have searched for answers and I could not find an answer for this case. Most of them were just finding the max value between the two tables and returning the max values and not the entire row. I have also fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use greatest for get the bigger between max values and filter for matching value on  Customer_ID, Priority or Customer_ID, PriorityOverride

```
  select Customer_ID, Date, Trigger, Priority, PriorityOverRide
  from offers 
  where (Customer_ID, Priority) in (
    SELECT
        Customer_ID,
        max( case when Priority >  PriorityOverride
          THEN Priority
          ELSE  PriorityOverride
        end )
    FROM  offers
    GROUP BY  CUstomer_ID
  ) 
  or  (Customer_ID, PriorityOverride) in (
    SELECT
        Customer_ID,
        max(case when Priority >  PriorityOverride
          THEN Priority
          ELSE  PriorityOverride
        end )
    FROM  offers
    GROUP BY  CUstomer_ID
  )
```

Comment: I initially went with using Greatest however the system does not support this syntax.

Comment: Note that trigger is a reserved word. Apart from that, there's no syntax error in the first query (although there is one in the second)

Comment: The second query gives a non-boolean type specified error but I cant see where it would be causing that issue, the Priority numbers are in decimals from 0-1, would that be causing an issue?

@Strawberry, Im assuming you are referring to the bracket after the END?

Comment: Updated my initial query.

Comment: Im currently getting this error message "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.", I dont think the system likes two columns in the WHERE IN clause. Is there an alternative to that? Please see OP for the updated query.

Comment: which version of mysql you are using?

Comment: Its not traditional MySQL, its salesforce MySQL so the syntaxes are a bit different. The error message was caused by having two compare variables in the WHERE IN clause. I've decided to split the codes into two parts and it seems to work fine. Thanks for your answer as it gave me an idea of the approach.

Comment: @Peter  you are wellcome .